# Broken 32kHz Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I am trying to build a simple 32kHz crystal oscillator but I am seeing something strange. I am using a simple circuit in that the crystal is in feedback around a current starved inverter.

However, I am seeing something strange. The frequency of operation is correct but at edge of the clock, there a multiple transitions before it finally stays high (or low). I.e. the voltages are bouncing"

[image: scope output]

Comment: Post links to oscilloscope output and to schematic and we'll edit them into the post.

Comment: That behavior is called 'ringing', if i interpret your description correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it is "ringing". However do you know why this occurs? I will attach a scope output soon.

Comment: Also, please post a photograph of your circuit and scope probe.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer, but empirically I have found 32kHz crystals to be extremely sensitive to additional load capacitance and/or any form of resistive load.

Comment: A link to the 'scope output:

Comment: Sorry...accidentally hit enter: http://i.imgur.com/mIoZv.png

Comment: I would say its not ringing but chatter due to slow rising edges on inputs to your inverters. Are you using Schmitt-trigger inverters? A schematic of your complete circuit is needed to give any more certain analysis.

Comment: My comment was posted before the image - I would agree, that is not ringing.

Comment: No...I am not using Schmitt-trigger inverters...rather I am using a current starved inverter as the "amplifier". I wanted to see the range of operation with varying current. I will draw schematic and attach a link. I am confused regarding the term "chatter" what does this mean?

Comment: Please post a photograph of your circuit and scope probe.

Answer (score 1):

If the metal can of oscillator is not grounded, then it works as a capacitive load parallel to crystal. The MHz bursts are probably matching the time delay of second positive feedback of invertor when this capacitance is involved.

http://www.telluriantech.com/Effects_of_Grounding_on_Ceramic_SMD_Crystal.pdf

Replace crystal with 2-10pF variable cap and see if the oscillations will match the frequency of bursts.

Answer: Ground the can. It will move bursts to GHz. Also the crystal pins can be grounded through small capacitors.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am assuming that by can you mean the housing of the crystal...correct? There already pulling capacitors in parrallel with the crystal that go to ground.

Comment: Yes. The housing. Another mistake can be driving the crystal with too high power. The typical power should be in microwatt range. The crystal can be destroyed mechanically by milliwatt power.